# Match words surrounded by a character, but not the words inbetween those words

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match this kind of pattern of strings containing words surrounded by a pair of colons (every line is a separate string):

```
:foo::bar:
:foo:
:foo: :bar::test:
:foo: :bar: :test:
```

but I want the regex to fail on these kind of patterns:

```
:foo:something:bar:
:foo:something
some :bar:
:foo: some:bar: thing
:foo: some :bar: thing
```

(Note that there can be 0 or more spaces between the words)

I tried using this regex:

```js
re = /^(:.*?: ?)+$/gm
```

but it fails (as in it matches) on the second set of examples. Is there any way to somehow fail the regex when there are words inbetween or before/after the colon-surrounded words?

Comment: `/^:[^:\n]+:(?: *:[^:\n]+:)*$/gm`, see https://regex101.com/r/A1cngm/1

Comment: You can use: `/^(?::[^:]+: *)+$/gm`

Comment: Thanks, these seems to work, feel free to post these as answers if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat matching the words between `:` on the left and right if there have to be 1 or more word characters `\w+` only.

Note that the `.` can also match `:` in the pattern that you tried.

```
^:\w+:(?: *:\w+:)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YEZDvv/1)

If you don't want to match `: : : :`

```
^(?:: *[^:\s]*[^:]*: *)+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `: *[^:\s]*` Match `:` optional spaces, a non whitespace char other than `:`
  - `[^:]*: *` Then optionally match any char except `:` and then match the `:`
- `)+` Close non capture group and repeat 1+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aY97SZ/1)

Comment: I guess my examples are too narrow, but I wanted to match these kind of strings too: `:foo: :bar: :test:`

Comment: @whatthe please edit your question to better define your expected result, so the provided answers can be specific to your use case

Comment: @whatthe Then you can repeat the spaces for every iteration `^:\w+:(?: *:\w+:)*$` See https://regex101.com/r/YEZDvv/1

Comment: @whatthe I have added another example if there should at least be a non whitespace char other than `:` in between.